# c# parse json string to object when data at child level

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

How to parse json string to object when data is at child level?

My json data is like:

```
{"d":{'item':[{'id':'1','name':'test'}
,{'id':'2','name':'test2'}]}}
```

I was able to parse when data were at root level but not able to do in this case. I have gone through similar parsing questions but could not get solution.

The response is provided by 3rd party asmx service, it works well when called via jquery ajax call.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Recreate your JSON objects as classes and then deserialize it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So "item" is your parent class and then you have a list of items with the attributes id and name.

You can then select your child data from the deserialized object.
There is no good way to select child data directly without manipulating the string.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to your project to "System.Web.Extensions.dll". Then Try:

```
 var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var result = jss.Deserialize<List<object>>("[{'id':'1','name':'test'},{'id':'2','name':'test2'}]");
```

You will need use using System.Web.Script.Serialization.
You will need remove 'item':

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the json is returned by 3rd party asmx service, so can not change it's format. It works well on ajax call by jquery but not able to parse from c#

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode

```
@{
    var data = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode("{'items':[{'id':'1','name':'test'}, {'id':'2','name':'test2'}]}");
}
@data.items[0].name
@data.items[1].id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first create two classes that represents the object that you get from the webservice

```
public class First {
  public List<Second> item {get;set;} 
}

public class Second {
  public int Id {get;set}
  public string Name {get;set}
}
```

When use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to

```
First m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<First>("{"d":{'item':[{'id':'1','name':'test'},{'id':'2','name':'test2'}]}}");
```

The first d in the response could make things a bit difficult tho. You might need a third class with a d property.

But now you have a strongly typed response to play with :-)